# why python -m parentfolder.mod works for relative import

Tags: python-3.x

My code structure:

```
parentfolder/
    folder/
      __init__.py
      mod1.py
      mod2.py
```

`mod1` defines a function called `foo`.
Here is what inside `mod2.py`:

```
from .mod1 import foo 
foo()
```

When I executed `mod2.py` under `folder`:

```
>cd folder 
>python mod2.py
```

I got:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

After some search, it is suggested we should use `-m` on `parentfolder` to make it work, like

```
>cd parentfolder
>python -m folder.mod2
```

It works. `-m` tells python to execute a library file as a script. But I do not understand the magic of using `-m` here. Why can it make relative import work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has to do with how the Python interpreter determines the root of the package tree. If you run python using `-m` from within `parentfolder`, it uses `parentfolder` as the root, and so it understands that `mod1` and `mod2` are modules within the `folder` package. If you run them from within `folder`, it uses `folder` as the top level, and so it sees the `mod1` and `mod1` modules at the top level, rather than part of a package. You can't do relative imports between top-level modules, so you get an error.

There is a workaround, which is to set the `__package__` variable in `mod2.py` (and `mod1.py` too if you want to be able to run it as a script) to `folder`, so that the import system will know you're in a package, even if you didn't use the import machinery to find the file by it's package name. This capability was added in [PEP 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/), where you can read more about it. The suggested boilerplate from the PEP is:

```
if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
    __package__ = "expected.package.name"
```

In your case, you'd want `folder` in place of `expected.package.name`. All of this would need to be above the relative `import` in `mod2.py`. It might be cleaner to just remember to run the file with `python -m folder.mod2`!

Comment: When I ran it, I got `No module named folder`. Anything else I need pay attention to?

Comment: It's possible that you also need `parentfolder` to be in the Python module search path. You can set that with the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, or I suppose with `sys.path` inside the module you're running, if you're willing to hard-code even more stuff (not just the package name, but it's filesystem path too).